# pragmatic issue with rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

the problem is that I have a validation method including lots of if/else statements:

```
if (isBlank(applyLoan.principal)) {
  makeToast(R.string.wizard_alert_null_principal);
  return false;
}
if (!isValidDigital(applyLoan.principal)) {
  makeToast(R.string.wizard_alert_illegal_principal);
  return false;
}
if (isBlank(applyLoan.loanInstallment)) {
  makeToast(R.string.wizard_purpose_hint_installment);
  return false;
}
if (isBlank(applyLoan.loanFor)) {
  makeToast(R.string.wizard_purpose_hint_purpose);
  return false;
}
...(lots of these things)
```

I'm considering use filter operator but I don't know whether it's worthing or not, because after read the source code I found a lot of "new" object.

So from memory management perspection, is it worthing to replace if/else? And is there anything related I should know?

Comment: Quite abstract question, do you want to explain more why do you have the rx-java tag and what do you want to optimize?

Comment: Actually，I just want to put some validation in the ontextchanged callback directly, but I still use the if/else not filter due to the "big" Observable. This callback event will react many times and so does Observable after user input some text. So I don't know and I haven't seen rx memory management or something like this sort of talking coming out.

Comment: The code block in any observable will work in "the same way" as if you didn't have Rx. Think Rx plainly as an async task managing framework. So whenever e.g. the `onTextChanged()` is notifying the subscriber the specified code block, e.g. the above one will run.

Comment: Yeah, really appreciate your response and I agree with your "the same way". But what I mean is the differences between filter operator and if/else, I mean they do have differences because of the way of implementation right? And the if/else won't take something extra objects along with tons of events(they are just a few validations), but after exploring in source code of "filter", I'm sure they are not just validations and I do have to unsubscribe their subscribers at the end of activity. So should I worry about it, am I on the right way?